# Spike in my reputations

Tags: support, reputation

Today when I opened physics stack exchange chemistry I found that my reputation spiked up to 495 whereas yesterday it was around 335(not much but still), for which I don't know how it happened? I just want to make sure if everything is OK as I don't know any reasons for this.

Comment: [speaking of spikes...](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/36793/srs) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the recent reputation change that Stack Exchange has made. Question upvotes are now worth +10 rep.

Read [here](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) for more information.